# Как называется сущность, которую мы создаем через systemd

Tags: linux, systemd

myservice@.service - это служба.
А как называется сущность, которую мы запускаем через эту службу (например sh скрипт)?

Comment: `Программа`, например?

Comment: Процесс?. . . .